# Why isn’t my slider responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow

I’m trying to make my slider responsive but I can’t. All the codes are here. I use Bootstrap to make the slider responsive. It looks like I am missing something. If I’m doing it in a wrong way you can send me tutorial links that will be appreciated.

#### HTML

```html
<div class="container">       
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xm-12 col-lg-12 img-responsive">
            <div id="slideShow"></div>                       
        </div>
    </div>          
</div> <!-- container -->
```

#### CSS

```css
#slideShow {
}

#slideShow img{  
    position: absolute;   // if i delete then the slider becomes responsive the images don't work as a slide  //
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    -o-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
}
#slideShow .current{
    opacity: 1;
}
body{
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```js
window.onload = function(){    
    /* code for image slideshow  */
    var imgsrc = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg"];
    for(var i = 1; i<=imgsrc.length; i++)
    {
        var slideShow = document.getElementById("slideShow");
        var newImage = new Image();
        newImage.src = "image/" + imgsrc[i];
        slideShow.appendChild(newImage);   
    }
    slideShow.childNodes[0].setAttribute("class","current img-responsive");
    var x = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        slideShow.childNodes[x%3].setAttribute("class","img-responsive");
        slideShow.childNodes[(x+1)%3].setAttribute("class","current img-responsive");
    x++;
    },3000);  
    /* end of code for image slideshow  */   
};  // end of window onload function
```

Comment: try this http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Answer (score 0):

Because you only have `col-md-12` set as a class - you should also add `col-xs-**` or `col-sm-**`. See https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: <div class="container">       
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xm-12 col-lg-12">
                                <div id="slideShow" class="img-responsive"></div>                       
                            </div>
                        </div>          
                    </div> <!-- container -->        .......................  this code didn't work also.

Comment: actually it works if I don't use position: absolute. what's the solution?

Comment: ...don't use `position:absolute`, you said it yourself.

Comment: but if i don't use position:absolute then how can the images will be displaying on the same place one after another.

Comment: The image shouldn't be absolutely positioned in this case anyway, you should put each image into it's own container, then position the container as necessary.